# Prove $\sigma(\tau(I))=(\sigma\tau)(I)$

Tags: calculus, matrices, summation, matrix-calculus

$I=(i_1,...,i_k)$ denotes an ordered $k$-tuple of indices.

Given $\sigma\in S_k$, define $\sigma(I)=(i_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},...,i_{\sigma^{-1}(k)})$

Let $\sigma,\tau\in S_k$. Then $\sigma(\tau(I))=(\sigma\tau)(I)$

Proof:

(1) Let $J=(j_1,...,j_k)=\tau(I)$ and $K=(k_1,...,k_k)=\sigma(J)$. Then $j_r=i_{\tau^{-1}(r)}$ and $k_r=j_{\sigma^{-1}(r)}$ such that

(2) $k_r=i_{\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(r))}=i_{(\sigma\tau)^{-1}(r)}$

(3) Therefore $K$ which we defined to be $\sigma(\tau(I))$, is also given by $(\sigma\tau)(I)$

I understand the general argument of the proof but I dont understand the step in part (2) that $k_r=i_{\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(r))}$

Comment: Two comments: First, the notation $(k_1, \ldots, k_k)$ is a little awkward since $k$ is being used in two different ways.  Second, where did you use the Kronecker $\delta$, or why is that included in the question?

Comment: I agree with both of your comments, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (1), the index $r$ is arbitrary, so if you accept (1), then you have:
$$
k_r = j_{\sigma^{-1}(r)}
$$
and by substituting $\sigma^{-1}(r)$ in place of $r$,
$$
j_{\sigma^{-1}(r)} = i_{\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(r))}
$$